# Turtle window not opening with turtle.mainloop

Tags: python, python-turtle

I have the following code:

```html
import turtle

my_pen = turtle.Turtle()

window = turtle.Screen()
window.setup(width=1000, height=1000)
window.title('Tutorial')

my_pen.color("red")
my_pen.penup()
my_pen.goto(0, 0)
window.delay(1000)
my_pen.pendown()
window.delay(100)

my_pen.forward(100)
my_pen.left(90)

my_pen.forward(100)
my_pen.left(90)


turtle.mainloop()
```

When I try to run the code, the window opens and closes immediately. I am using the newest python 3.9, and I am using the newest PyCharm Community

I will attach a video of me running it and the window closing immediately
[image]

Comment: for me it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: first, I don't know that the `delay()` method is doing anything for you, it doesn't add anything in my environment, so I'd leave it out until you've debugged the rest of the code.

Second, your code works fine for me.  So I suggest you stop looking at the code and look at the environment in which you're running it.  You're not simply running Python at the console but rather using some sort of IDE (Idle?).  If so, you should include that information in your question.

A simple code clean up for testing purposes:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

window = Screen()
window.setup(width=1000, height=1000)
window.title('Tutorial')

my_pen = Turtle()
my_pen.color("red")

my_pen.forward(100)
my_pen.left(90)

my_pen.forward(100)
my_pen.left(90)

window.mainloop()
```